# Get index of elements nested in different divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, children

Is it possible to get the index of a checked input, where all of them are nested in different divs. eg such situation:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <input></input>
    <input></input>
    <input></input>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input checked="checked"></input>
    <input></input>
    <input></input>
  </div>
</div>
```

So the checked input would show

> index = 3

how to build such a selector? is it possible? Or is it just can show index of children nested directly withing the same parent?

Comment: Do you mean how deep is nested? or index of collection of inputs?

Comment: Why don't you use an id for each one of them? Also, you can add a value attribute everyone.

Comment: When do you want this index, on page load or when checkbox is checked? You want all the indexes as _array_ or just the first/last as number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to invoke `.index()` over the entire collection by passing the target element,

```
var inputs = $(".parent input:checkbox");
var index = inputs.index(inputs.filter(":checked")); //3
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gyf25jrp/)

A demonstration with valid html is given [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/rq2jve2y/).

Comment: Downvoter, please add comments, that'll help to improve answer. I don't see any reason for down voting as it is working fine.

Comment: Raja, just add `type="checkbox"` to `input`s to make them valid checkboxes, +1

Comment: @Tushar Thanks. Added it. :)

Comment: @Tushar Ah.. :D yes. Forget to update that.. Edited post with your fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

If you find all the inputs, you can do your index off of that collection.

http://jsfiddle.net/kyyh0gxe/

`var $inputs = $('.parent input');
console.log( $inputs.index( $inputs.filter(':checked') ) );`

Answer (score 0):

You can index any collection of elements

```
var $inputs = $('input:checkbox');
$inputs.change(function(){
    alert( $inputs.index(this) );
});
```

Or to map array of checked input inidices:

```
var checked = $('input:checked').map(function(){
    return $inputs.index(this);
}).get();
```

Comment: OP wants to check this on page load, so use `trigger` on the elements for first example see http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/rq2jve2y/1/, update the answer accordingly also feel free to add the fiddle in answer. Regarding second example, array is returned, OP might just want _number_. http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/rq2jve2y/2/

Comment: @Tushar you made that assumption, it was never stated in the question. Question was very vague in fact as to use case

Comment: Yes that is, but `index = 3` is what OP want as output, so you _know_ what OP is expecting

Comment: @Tushar that doesn't imply page load ... you are reading too much into a poor question. OP can figure it out from all the variations on this page. It's really not worth putting much more effort into this

Answer (score 0):

Get all the input in the page as a nodelist using getElementsByTagName,
then cycle trought the nodelist and verify which element from the nodelist has the checked proposition true. i is the index you are searching for.

```
var collection = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
  if (collection[i].checked) {
    ... do your stuff with i
  }
}
```

Comment: Please state why this solves the problem rather than just pasting code